# Reset Rich Edit control to default colors

Tags: c++, winapi, richedit

I am writing a plugin for Finale music program that uses a Rich Edit control to display and edit formatted text. One of the formats is a "hidden" style which really just means that it is grayed out. The "hidden"-ness only applies when Finale prints the text. It turns out `CFM_DISABLED`/`CFE_DISABLED` works exactly as I need for displaying a section of "hidden" text. It automatically grays out the text marked disabled, but otherwise it has no impact on the user's ability to edit the text.

Here is the code I use to do this:

```cpp
static CHARFORMAT2W charFormatFromFontInfo(const FCFontInfo *pFont)
{
    FCString fontName;
    pFont->GetNameString(&fontName);
    CHARFORMAT2W cf{};
    cf.cbSize = sizeof(cf);
    cf.dwMask = CFM_BOLD | CFM_FACE | CFM_ITALIC | CFM_SIZE | CFM_STRIKEOUT | CFM_UNDERLINE | CFM_DISABLED;
    lstrcpynW(cf.szFaceName, (LPCWSTR)fontName._GetUnicodeBuffer(), DIM(cf.szFaceName));
    cf.szFaceName[DIM(cf.szFaceName) - 1] = 0;
    
    cf.yHeight = 20.0 * pFont->GetSizeFloat(); // points to twps
    
    if (pFont->GetBold())
        cf.dwEffects |= CFE_BOLD;
    if (pFont->GetItalic())
        cf.dwEffects |= CFE_ITALIC;
    if (pFont->GetUnderline())
        cf.dwEffects |= CFE_UNDERLINE;
    if (pFont->GetStrikeOut())
        cf.dwEffects |= CFE_STRIKEOUT;
    if (pFont->GetHidden())
        cf.dwEffects |= CFE_DISABLED;
    
    return cf;
}
```

The problem comes when I add color ranges to the control. When I add a color to a range of text, the control loses any visible representation of "disabled"-ness if a disabled passage overlaps the range where I change the color. That's okay for my purposes, but I would like to be able to reset the colors and regain the display of disabled sections as grayed-out. I can't figure out how to do this. I have tried, simply:

```cpp
    // after setting the selection to the entire text
    CHARFORMAT2W cf{};
    cf.cbSize = sizeof(cf);
    cf.dwMask = CFM_COLOR;
    cf.crTextColor = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION | SCF_DEFAULT, (LPARAM)&cf);
```

This restored the black text, but it also changed all the disabled text black as well.

ChatGPT suggested setting the `cf.crTextColor` member to -1, but that was a hallucination. (It didn't work.)

My question boils down to, is there a way to back out all the color changes and restore the default behavior where `CFE_DISABLED` text is grayed out?

Comment: As a workaround, can you query the default colors in the beginning, and at restore time set color to the previous query result?

Comment: A number of workarounds come to mind, but I was hoping to avoid adding a lot of complexity for a fairly rare situation.

Comment: It looks like one workaround would be to read the formatted text out of the control (without colors), set it to zero length, then write it back in using my function about (without setting in colors). I might use that as a solution if no one comes up with a better.

Comment: Sheesh. The answer is staring us in the face: `CFE_AUTOCOLOR`. <facepalm>. I think the docs could be more descriptive, but anyway that's the answer. Will update when SO allows it.

Comment: You can also answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the `CFE_AUTOCOLOR` flag. The Microsoft documents are not completely clear on this point, but it is the solution.

```cpp
    // after setting the selection to the entire text
    CHARFORMAT2W cf{};
    cf.cbSize = sizeof(cf);
    cf.dwMask = CFM_COLOR;
    cf.dwEffects = CFM_AUTOCOLOR;
    cf.crTextColor = RGB(0, 0, 0); // may not strictly be necessary but is clean
    SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION | SCF_DEFAULT, (LPARAM)&cf);
```

This causes the text to be colored with system defaults, which includes graying out text marked with `CFM_DISABLED`.